Credential Manager causes ProtoDataStoreConfig<xgc> doesn't match previous call
From the official page of Sign in your user with Credential Manager, it is clearly written there

Credential Manager is a Jetpack API that supports multiple sign-in methods, such as username and password, passkeys, and federated sign-in solutions (such as Sign-in with Google) in a single API, thus simplifying the integration for developers.


Furthermore, for users, Credential Manager unifies the sign-in interface across authentication methods, making it clearer and easier for users to sign into apps, regardless of the method they choose.

I have added required dependencies:
#noinspection CredentialDependency
androidx-credentials = { module = "androidx.credentials:credentials", version.ref = "credentials" }
androidx-credentials-play-services-auth = { module = "androidx.credentials:credentials-play-services-auth", version.ref = "credentials" }
googleid = { module = "com.google.android.libraries.identity.googleid:googleid", version.ref = "googleid" }

Gradle build file is:
// Added dependencies
// Credential Manager
implementation(libs.androidx.credentials)
implementation(libs.androidx.credentials.play.services.auth)
implementation(libs.googleid)

I have a composable function
@Composable
fun GoogleSignInButton() {

    val context = LocalContext.current
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    val onClick = {
        val rawNonce = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
        val md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256")

        val digest = md.digest(rawNonce.toByteArray())
        val hashedNonce = digest.fold("") { str, it -> str + "%02x".format(it) }

        val credentialManager = CredentialManager.create(context)
        val googleIdOption: GetGoogleIdOption = GetGoogleIdOption.Builder()
            .setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(false)
            .setServerClientId("xxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com")
            .setNonce(hashedNonce)
            .setAutoSelectEnabled(false)
            .build()

        val request: GetCredentialRequest = GetCredentialRequest.Builder()
            .addCredentialOption(googleIdOption)
            .build()

        scope.launch {
            try {
                val credentialResponse = credentialManager.getCredential(
                    request = request,
                    context = context
                )

                val credential = credentialResponse.credential
                val googleIdTokenCredential = GoogleIdTokenCredential
                    .createFrom(credential.data)

                val googleIdToken = googleIdTokenCredential.idToken

                Log.d("GoogleSignInButton", "Google ID Token: $googleIdToken")
                // Proceed with using the Google ID token for authentication.
                Toast.makeText(context, "Signed In!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            } catch (e: GetCredentialCancellationException){
                e.printStackTrace()
            } catch (e: GetCredentialException){
                e.printStackTrace()
            } catch (e: GoogleIdTokenParsingException){
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }

    }

    Button(onClick = {
        onClick()
    }) {
        Text(text = "SignIn with Google")
    }
}

MainActivity is
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContent {
            CredentialsTheme {
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                ) {
                    GoogleSignInButton()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

There are many (more than one) google accounts on a device, with the above code, when I sign in with some account it works, but when I re-sign in using different account, it gives me error:
2024-08-12 14:40:57.419  3829-3829  System.err              com.being.coder.app.credentials      W  androidx.credentials.exceptions.NoCredentialException: During begin sign in, failure response from one tap: 8: [8] UNKNOWN EXCEPTION - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ProtoDataStoreConfig<xgc> doesn't match previous call [uri=android://com.google.android.gms/files/auth_api_credentials/com.google%3Amyemailaddress%40gmail.com/gislamssettings.pb] [variantConfig]
2024-08-12 14:40:57.427  3829-3829  System.err              com.being.coder.app.credentials      W      at androidx.credentials.playservices.controllers.CredentialProviderBaseController$Companion.getCredentialExceptionTypeToException$credentials_play_services_auth_release(CredentialProviderBaseController.kt:110)
2024-08-12 14:40:57.427  3829-3829  System.err              com.being.coder.app.credentials      W      at androidx.credentials.playservices.controllers.BeginSignIn.CredentialProviderBeginSignInController$resultReceiver$1$onReceiveResult$1.invoke(CredentialProviderBeginSignInController.kt:93)
2024-08-12 14:40:57.427  3829-3829  System.err              com.being.coder.app.credentials      W      at androidx.credentials.playservices.controllers.BeginSignIn.CredentialProviderBeginSignInController$resultReceiver$1$onReceiveResult$1.invoke(CredentialProviderBeginSignInController.kt:93)
2024-08-12 14:40:57.427  3829-3829  System.err              com.being.coder.app.credentials      W      at androidx.credentials.playservices.controllers.CredentialProviderController.maybeReportErrorFromResultReceiver(CredentialProviderController.kt:159)
2024-08-12 14:40:57.427  3829-3829  System.err              com.being.coder.app.credentials      W      at androidx.credentials.playservices.controllers.BeginSignIn.CredentialProviderBeginSignInController.access$maybeReportErrorFromResultReceiver(CredentialProviderBeginSignInController.kt:56)
2024-08-12 14:40:57.427  3829-3829  System.err              com.being.coder.app.credentials      W      at androidx.credentials.playservices.controllers.BeginSignIn.CredentialProviderBeginSignInController$resultReceiver$1.onReceiveResult(CredentialProviderBeginSignInController.kt:91)
2024-08-12 14:40:57.428  3829-3829  System.err              com.being.coder.app.credentials      W      at android.os.ResultReceiver$MyRunnable.run(ResultReceiver.java:50)
2024-08-12 14:40:57.428  3829-3829  System.err              com.being.coder.app.credentials      W      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
2024-08-12 14:40:57.428  3829-3829  System.err              com.being.coder.app.credentials      W      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
2024-08-12 14:40:57.428  3829-3829  System.err              com.being.coder.app.credentials      W      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:186)
2024-08-12 14:40:57.428  3829-3829  System.err              com.being.coder.app.credentials      W      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6513)
2024-08-12 14:40:57.428  3829-3829  System.err              com.being.coder.app.credentials      W      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2024-08-12 14:40:57.428  3829-3829  System.err              com.being.coder.app.credentials      W      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:914)
2024-08-12 14:40:57.428  3829-3829  System.err              com.being.coder.app.credentials      W      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:804)

My Device uses Android 7.1, I have tested this conde on Android 11 and Android 12, but same error, Kindly help me in this case
Project is available here Credentials

hmm, I have the same problem with android 6.01 en 7. But in android 14 the problem is solved.
